# Calculate weighted scores via column heading lookup in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, lookup

I have a data entry sheet with multiple columns, and the user is allowed to input a number in each cell.

I have a separate table with a weighting based on each Column's heading.

The desired output I need is the total weighted score per row (sum of the input numbers multiplied by the associated weight based on the column header).  How can I do this?

Input data:
[image]

Weight table:
[image]

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP()` and additional (hidden?) row (maybe on separate 'worksheet for calculations').

Answer (score 0):

You have a weighting table that is in alphabetical order, and matching column headings that are in some other order (presumably intentional).  Rather than do a lookup for every case, I would do the lookup once and create a weighting list in the same sequence as the column headings.  Then the task becomes simple.

[image]

I just used letter placeholders for your column headings to keep things simple (well actually, because I didn't want to type all that stuff).  :-)

Your data is in rows 1 and 2 and the weighting table is in A9:B16.

You could create the translated table in row 6 via sorting and transposing, but I used this formula (for A6):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$A$9:$B$16,2)
```

Copying that across looks up each heading in the table and returns its associated weight.  That translated list can be stuck anywhere, even hidden.  The formula ties the value to the heading, but if you want to move the translated list to another location, you can copy the headings to the row above the list to serve as labels.

Getting the score uses SUMPRODUCT, which does in one formula exactly what you want to do, multiplies each input value by its associated weight and adds up the results:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:H2,$A$6:$H$6)
```

The reference to the translated weights uses absolute addressing, so you can have multiple rows of input and copy the score formula to as many rows as you need.